# Powershell and System Center "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Tags: powershell, reboot, sccm

I'm trying to create a script that runs on my clients computers and checks for a pending reboot. If there is a pending reboot it pops up a message that asks the user to reboot or defer. This works great when I try it on my local computer. However, once I put it into System Center and deploy it, it does not run and I get the error "Warning: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" Any ideas? Here is the script

```psh
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias("CN","Computer")]
    [String[]]$ComputerName="$env:COMPUTERNAME",
    [String]$ErrorLog
    )

Begin
    {
        # Adjusting ErrorActionPreference to stop on all errors, since using [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]
        # does not have a native ErrorAction Parameter, this may need to be changed if used within another
        # function.
        $TempErrAct = $ErrorActionPreference
        $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    }#End Begin Script Block
Process
    {
        Foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName)
            {
                Try
                    {
                        # Setting pending values to false to cut down on the number of else statements
                        $PendFileRename,$Pending,$SCCM = $false,$false,$false

                        # Setting CBSRebootPend to null since not all versions of Windows has this value
                        $CBSRebootPend = $NULL


                        # Querying WMI for build version
                        $WMI_OS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Property BuildNumber, CSName -ComputerName $Computer

                        # Making registry connection to the local/remote computer
                        $RegCon = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]"LocalMachine",$Computer)

                        # If Vista/2008 & Above query the CBS Reg Key

                        If ($WMI_OS.BuildNumber -ge 6001)
                            {
                                $RegSubKeysCBS = $RegCon.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\").GetSubKeyNames()
                                $CBSRebootPend = $RegSubKeysCBS -contains "RebootPending"

                            }#End If ($WMI_OS.BuildNumber -ge 6001)

                        # Query WUAU from the registry
                        $RegWUAU = $RegCon.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\")
                        $RegWUAURebootReq = $RegWUAU.GetSubKeyNames()
                        $WUAURebootReq = $RegWUAURebootReq -contains "RebootRequired"

                        # Closing registry connection
                        $RegCon.Close()

                        # Determine SCCM 2012 Client Reboot Pending Status
                        # To avoid nested 'if' statements and unneeded WMI calls to determine if the CCM_ClientUtilities class exist, setting EA = 0
                        $CCMClientSDK = $null
                        $CCMSplat = @{
                            NameSpace='ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK'
                            Class='CCM_ClientUtilities'
                            Name='DetermineIfRebootPending'
                            ComputerName=$Computer
                            ErrorAction='SilentlyContinue'
                            }
                        $CCMClientSDK = Invoke-WmiMethod @CCMSplat
                        If ($CCMClientSDK)
                            {
                                If ($CCMClientSDK.ReturnValue -ne 0)
                                    {
                                        Write-Warning "Error: DetermineIfRebootPending returned error code $($CCMClientSDK.ReturnValue)"

                                    }#End If ($CCMClientSDK -and $CCMClientSDK.ReturnValue -ne 0)

                                If ($CCMClientSDK.IsHardRebootPending -or $CCMClientSDK.RebootPending)
                                    {
                                        $SCCM = $true

                                    }#End If ($CCMClientSDK.IsHardRebootPending -or $CCMClientSDK.RebootPending)

                            }#End If ($CCMClientSDK)
                        Else
                            {
                                $SCCM = $null

                            }                        

                        # If any of the variables are true, set $Pending variable to $true
                        If ($CBSRebootPend -or $WUAURebootReq -or $SCCM)
                            {
                                $Pending = $true

                            }#End If ($CBS -or $WUAU)


                        If ($Pending = $CBSRebootPend -or $WUAURebootReq -or $SCCM)
                            {
                                $a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell
                                $b = $a.popup(“A Reboot is Pending, Press ""OK"" to reboot now or ""Cancel"" to reboot later.“,240,”CRISTA IT”,1)
                                if($b -eq 1) {
                                                Restart-Computer
                                            }

                                if($b -eq 2) {

                                #cancle was selected in the box. So should exit
                                exit(1)
                                            }


                            }

                    }#End Try

                Catch
                    {
                        Write-Warning "$Computer`: $_"

                        # If $ErrorLog, log the file to a user specified location/path
                        If ($ErrorLog)
                            {
                                Out-File -InputObject "$Computer`,$_" -FilePath $ErrorLog -Append

                            }#End If ($ErrorLog)

                    }#End Catch

            }#End Foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName)

    }#End Process

End
    {
        # Resetting ErrorActionPref
        $ErrorActionPreference = $TempErrAct
    }#End End
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** I did not create this script fully but used different free scripts online to create this.

Comment: What line creates the error?

Comment: I'm not sure? When I run it out of powershell ISE it runs without a problem, The window comes up asking to reboot and you can reboot or cancel. Once I get it into Software Center and deploy it powershell pops up and says "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." and doesn't run at all.

Comment: Now I am curious about what PowerShell version you are running and if that is what is on the clients. I wonder if you have 3.0 and your clients have 2.0 as I could see this line `$RegSubKeysCBS = $RegCon.....` failing on 2.0. Have you tried running this locally on another computer?

Comment: Why are you using a `foreach` if this will only target the machine it is running from? That could be what is causing the issue

Comment: @Matt When I run it locally on the computer I'm deploying to from Software Center it works fine. Works locally on all comptuers, Does not work from out of Software Center.....

Comment: @Luke I modified the script from another script. Is there a better way then 'foreach'?

Comment: @Luke So I took out the foreach and just replaced everything with $env:COMPUTERNAME and ran it in through Software center again and I'm still getting the same Error about null valued expressions :/

Comment: it sounds like it is not getting the environment variable... whichever machine you are going to test push it out to hardcode the computer name in there and see if it will work.

Comment: @Luke I gave that a try and still got the "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" I don't think its pulling the computer name that is the issue :/ any other ideas?

Comment: @Luke Actually it looks like it is something with the way its pulling computername.....

Comment: how are you trying to have SCCM deploy this? how is it running on the client machines
?

Comment: @Luke I have a package that runs the command line **"Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NoProfile -File .\PendingRebootScript.ps1"** Running with "User rights" (I've tried as admin as well)

Comment: and I can assume that you have tested the command line works on your local machine, you could try passing the `localhost` for the computername in the command line and see if that will work.

Comment: @Luke When I run it from Command line it works perfectly without a problem. I tried it with localhost and get the same results :/

Comment: so when your package has the command line **"Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NoProfile -File .\PendingRebootScript.ps1 -computername localhost "** it still returns null... let me think on this.

Comment: maybe introduce some basic logging to see at which point the script fails and then narrow it down to the line it errors out? may not be the most inspiring way but allways works :) or just create a transcript if possible

Comment: did you try to make a .bat file and start the powershell from the bat file on the remote machines? maybe there is a funky way SCCM is sending the command.